# Querying through java

Tags: java, postgresql, querying

I have two tables: harvested_record and harvested_record_simple_keys there are in relation one-to-one.

```
harvested_record

id|harvested_record_simple_keys_id|a lot of columns



harvested_record_simple_keys

id| a lot of columns
```

and I want to make a query in which I need to join there two tables. As a result I will have a table:

```
joined_table
id(harvested_record)| (harvested_record_simple_keys)|a lot of columns.
```

Unfortunately I get an exception: `nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column name 'ID' matches more than one result column.`

I've understood this is because after join I will have two columns 'id'. Does anyone can help me with solution?

P.S.
SQL statement(works in IDEA console):

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT TMP_ORDERED.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS ROW_NUMBER FROM (SELECT * FROM harvested_record hr JOIN harvested_record_simple_keys hrsk ON hrsk.id = hr.harvested_record_simple_keys_id WHERE import_conf_id = ? ) AS TMP_ORDERED) AS TMP_SUB WHERE TMP_SUB.ROW_NUMBER <= 2 ORDER BY import_conf_id ASC, record_id ASC;
```

Java code(suppose error is here):

```
JdbcPagingItemReader<HarvestedRecord> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<HarvestedRecord>();
SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean pqpf = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
pqpf.setDataSource(dataSource);
pqpf.setSelectClause("SELECT *");
pqpf.setFromClause("FROM harvested_record hr JOIN harvested_record_simple_keys hrsk ON hrsk.id = hr.harvested_record_simple_keys_id");

String whereClause = "WHERE import_conf_id = :configId";
if (from!=null) {
    fromStamp = new Timestamp(from.getTime());
    whereClause += " AND updated >= :from";
}
if (to!=null) {
    toStamp = new Timestamp(to.getTime());
    whereClause += " AND updated <= :to";
}

if (configId != null) {
    pqpf.setWhereClause(whereClause);
}

pqpf.setSortKeys(ImmutableMap.of("import_conf_id",
        Order.ASCENDING, "record_id", Order.ASCENDING));
reader.setRowMapper(harvestedRecordRowMapper);
reader.setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE);
reader.setQueryProvider(pqpf.getObject());
reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
if (configId != null) {
    Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameterValues.put("configId", configId);
    parameterValues.put("from", fromStamp );
    parameterValues.put("to", toStamp);
    reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
}
reader.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just as the errors tells you, multiple columns have the same name. You need to define aliases for these columns. "Select col AS col1 FROM ..."

Comment: In tables I have a lot of columns and I would not want write names for every column.

Comment: you may have done more typing here in Stack Overflow than it would have taken to type out the column names :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you name your columns in the select statement instead of using 'SELECT *', you can omit the ID from one of the tables since it is always equal to the id from the other table.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have no idea how to make query with semantic:
SELECT *[except some_id] FROM...